# AWS CLI Storage for android backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nosql, aws-amplify, aws-storage-gateway

I want to store some data in database. I created a NoSQL database using Amplify Storage. But cannot find how to add data to the database. Please help?